# How to disable cascaded Kendo DropDownLists?

Tags: c#, javascript, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have two Kendo DropDownLists, I want to disable second DDL when the value of the first DDL is loaded and bounded to the value of my viewmodel.

So I have such code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("FormGroupId")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px" })
      .OptionLabel("Select form group...")
      .Template("#= data.Name # - #= data.Version #")
      .DataTextField("Name")
      .DataValueField("Id")
      .Events(events =>
      {
          events.Change("onFormGroupChanged");
          events.Select("onFormGroupSelected");
          events.Cascade("onFormGroupCascaded");
      })
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
            source.Read(read => { read.Route(RouteConfig.GetFormGroupNames.Name); });
      })
)
```

and

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("Schema")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px" })
      .OptionLabel("Select schema...")
      .DataTextField("SchemaName")
      .DataValueField("SchemaId")
      .DataSource(source => 
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Route(RouteConfig.FilterFormSchemas.Name).Data("filterSchemas");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(true);
      })
      .Enable(false)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .CascadeFrom("FormGroupId")
)
```

I subscribe to the Cascade event on first DDL and try to disable second DDL from there, but it doesn't work.

JS:

```
function onFormGroupCascaded(e) {
    $("#Schema").data("kendoDropDownList").enable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You are already doing that.

Add events to first drop-down list:

```
.Events(e =>
{
    e.Change("change").Select("select").Open("open").Close("close").DataBound("dataBound");
})
```

Using JavaScript, handle the change event

```
<script>
    function change() {
        // get a reference to the dropdown list
        var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");
        // disable the dropdown list
        dropdownlist.enable(false);
    };
</script>
```

Looks like you are already doing this. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that will not work. At least in my case it did not. Code in the Kendo library simply re-enables the drop down later.

Comment: bind to the DataBound event to disable the drop down instead as @LukeFranklin 's answer.

Comment: that really worked for me. I have been looking for this answer for hours. thank you.

Comment: not work , cascade event is after of all events

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but binding to the `CascadeFrom` event will not prevent the drop down from being enabled. This is due to code in the Kendo library re-enabling it later in the execution order.

Instead, bind to the `DataBound` event to disable the drop down. This event occurs later in the execution stack and disables the input after the Kendo code enables it.

Comment: Can you please give a bit more detail here?

Comment: What's not clear? By default the Kendo DropDown will be enabled after the CascadeFrom event is fired.

Comment: Erm, I meant a bit more detailed about the second paragraph ;-) (I'm a complete beginner with Kendo, apologies.)

Comment: I might have to point you to the docs for that one: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/events

Comment: Once you get a bit more familiar with Kendo it should make sense. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This code works in angular directive configuration

```
dataBound: function (e) {
            this.enable(false);
        }
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com) accepts **code-only answer** like this, but it isn't *very* help for others. Please [edit] your answer and explain *How does your code work*. Sometimes, also *Why doesn't OP's code work*.